# Typescript optimizes emitted declarations

Tags: typescript

I have code in my library where I expect `PluginsInterface` interface to be augmented by the user

```
import { PluginsInterface } from 'peer-dep'

export const myPlugin<T = PluginsInterface extends { $plugin: infer U } ? U : any>(){}
```

The user would augment it like so

```
declare module "peer-dep" {
  interface PluginsInterface {
    $plugin: unknown;
  }
}
```

but after emitting declarations I get

```
export declare const myPlugin<T = any>(){}
```

Is there a way to make this work?

I've tried to describe the problem as more generic, but if it helps
[here](https://github.com/PatrykWalach/vue-redux-hooks/blob/master/src/hooks/useSelector.ts) is a github link to my library

Comment: I am confused by your syntax. To me `I extends...` refers to a generic, not to the interface you import.

Comment: @geoffrey I've made some changes and attached a link to the library, hope that help

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't the type you're looking to extract just `PluginsInterface["$plugin"]`? It seems like conceptually you're trying to defer this extraction, but there's nothing to defer it to since it's still all compile-time.

Comment: @IngoBürk The `PluginsInterface` is empty at the start.
In my project user should create redux store, augment the interface, and provide it for all vue components
`declare module "peer-dep" {
  interface PluginsInterface {
    $redux: typeof store;
  }
}`
then he should be able to call `useSelector((state) => state)` and he wouldn't have to type the state. My library doesn't know what kind of store user will create. It is possible to type the state every time `useSelector((state: State) => state)`, or create a hooks factory, but I think It wouldn't be as efficient.

Comment: Augmenting the interface is standard pattern in `vue`. What I'm trying to do is extract the type after user augmented the interface. However typescript compiler doesn't know that the interface will be augmented so he trims the conditional clause.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug, it works for

```
export function myPlugin<T = PluginsInterface extends { $plugin: infer U } ? U : any>(){}
```

but not for an arrow function

```
export const myPlugin = <T = PluginsInterface extends { $plugin: infer U } ? U : any>() => {}
```